# Is it possible to create a Calendar object like Tue Mar 03 13:43:00 (without time zone)?

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I have a requirement of sending the calendar object with time zone, like `Tue Mar 03 13:43:00`. I know that Calendar object always return with `Tue Mar 03 13:43:00 CST 2009`, so how can I create it without the time zone?

Comment: With or without a time zone, which is it? You question and its title contradict each other.

Comment: @kamal: I've tried to clarify your question. If I misunderstood it, please correct it.

Comment: I am looking for a Calendar object without time zone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class (more specifically the [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) concrete subclass) to format the date however you want.  Here is an example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

String dateString = format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Prints:

```
Fri Mar 06 15:50:26
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the services which I am calling is looking for Calendar object so I can't use DateFormat ...

Comment: Calendar.getTime() returns a Date object.. see the code I just posted.

Comment: thanks Kip for sharing the code but it still not going to solve my problem since I need to pass  a Calendar object to the service with time zone

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a Calendar object without a TimeZone. Really, that doesn't make any sense - Calendar seeks to represent "[a specific instant in time](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)" - how can you represent an instance in time without knowing what TimeZone the time you are representing is in?

So, there's a few things to consider:

1. You say you need to pass this Calendar to some other component - does that API care what TimeZone the Calendars are in? Will that API ignore the TimeZone setting, use it to calculate a time difference against it's own local timezone, etc.?
2. Are you aware that you can easily change the TimeZone of a Calendar instance?

   ```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); // returns default TimeZone for your system
   cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")); // Eastern Standard Time
   cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkota"); // UTC+5:30
   ```

Javadocs on [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), [TimeZone](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

Comment: btw looks like Calendar.setTimeZone(null) would cause some errors; which seems to support the notion that a Calendar is very closely tied to and needs it's TimeZone reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Date object using;

```
Date d = new Date();
Date d2 = calendar.getTime();
```

Or the even simpler, time in milli-seconds.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

To avoid confusion over time zones, I suggest storing and setting all date/times as a standard time zone, such as GMT+0 and then converting the time for display etc as required.

Answer (score 0):

Upon rereading your question and your comments on my other answer, it sounds like the problem is that you want the result to be a Calendar object, not a String.  So it isn't a question of formatting the String representation of the Calendar.

In this case, what you are asking is technically impossible: all implementations of the Calendar class exist to represent an internal time, which is stored as the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1 1970 00:00 GMT).  The time "5:00 am" in Boston is different from "5:00 am" in Seattle--they have different internal timestamps.

Your best bet would be to use the same time zone everywhere, and probably GMT makes the most sense for that purpose:

```
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0000"));
```